# Error while executing DetEval software to evaluate the performance of my text recognition algorithm

Tags: xml-parsing, text-recognition

I have come up with a text recognition algorithm. This algorithm recognizes text in natural images. I am trying to test it against the [groundtruth available for the dataset of ICDAR's robust reading challenge.](http://robustreading.opendfki.de/wiki/SceneText) For this, I have generated an xml file containing coordinates of text regions in a scene image, as recognized by my algorithm. A similar xml file is provided for the groundtruth data.

To generate quantitative results of comparison of the two xml files, i am required to use [DetEval software](http://liris.cnrs.fr/christian.wolf/software/deteval/commandline.html) (as mentioned in the site). I have installed a command line version on linux.

The problem is: DetEval is not reading the input xml files. Specifically,

I run the following command (As per the instructions on the [DetEval website](http://liris.cnrs.fr/christian.wolf/software/deteval/commandline.html)): 
**rocplot /home/ekta/workspace/extract/result_ICDAR_2011/txt/GT2.xml { /home/ekta/workspace/extract/result_ICDAR_2011/txt/final.xml }**

Here, GT2.xml is the groundtruth and final.xml is the file generated by my algorithm.

I get the following error message:
**evaldetection -p 0.8,0.4,0.8,0.4,0.4,0.8,0,1 "{" "/home/ekta/workspace/extract/result_ICDAR_2011/txt/GT2.xml" | readdeteval -p 1 - >> /tmp/evaldetectioncurves20130818-21541-1kum9m9-0
evaldetection -p 0.8,0.4,0.8,0.4,0.4,0.8,0,1 "{" "/home/ekta/workspace/extract/result_ICDAR_2011/txt/GT2.xml"I/O warning : failed to load external entity "{"
Couldn't parse document {
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
^
-:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
^
I/O error : Invalid seek
Couldn't parse document -
rocplot:**  ERROR  **running the command:
evaldetection -p 0.8,0.4,0.8,0.4,0.4,0.8,0,1 "{" "/home/ekta/workspace/extract/result_ICDAR_2011/txt/GT2.xml" | readdeteval -p 1 - >> /tmp/evaldetectioncurves20130818-21541-1kum9m9-0Error code: 256**

What do i do? I am positive that there is no error in generating my xml file because even the groundtruth file obtained from the website is not being parsed. Please help!

Regards
Ekta

Answer (score 2):

So, I managed to solve this issue. Turns out I was giving the wrong commands. rocplots is to be used only when I need to have multiple runs on the ground truth and detection files with varying evaluation parameters. See [this](http://liris.cnrs.fr/christian.wolf/papers/tr-liris-2005-wolfjolion.pdf) paper to know more about the parameters involved.

Currently, I have one ground truth file and one detection file and I need to run it using just the default parameters used by DetEval. So, here is what needs to be done:

Go to directory where you have **detevalcmd** directory and enter **detevalcmd** directory. Run the following commands in that directory:

1. ./evaldetection /path/to/detection/results/DetectionFilename.xml /path/to/ground/truth/file/GroundTruthFilename.xml > /path/where/you/want/to/store/results/result.xml

This will store the results in result.xml. Next, run the following command:
2. ./readdeteval /path/where/you/stored/results/result.xml.

This will give something like:

```
**100% of the images contain objects.
Generality: xxx
Inverse-Generality: xxx
  <evaluation noImages="xxx">
    <icdar2003 r="xxx" p="xxx" hmean="xxx" noGT="XXX" noD="xxx"/>
    <score r="Xxx" p="xxx" hmean="xxx" noGT="xxx" noD="xxx"/>
  </evaluation>**
```

So, there you go! you got the recall, precision etc. for you algorithm.